# MS Graph API Teams: Get messages count

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I need get messages count from all teams, channels or get count from chats. It's needed for show notifications in my applications.
Is this possible get messages count or list messages?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can use the beta version of [the Microsoft Graph API to work with Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta)

But, there is no dorect API for getting the message count. You can only get [messages in a chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) or [messages in a channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).

In the response, you will get the messages count of this page, and the link for next page. You may get the messages count by fetching each page and add the count of each page. It is a optional workaround at the present.

[image]